# Should and can I avoid passing UnitOfWork instance to strategies through methods?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, unit-of-work

Imagine that I have one method like below that is using some strategies to create new products and persists them as a result in the Db.

And everything happens as a part of a Unit of Work.

**(My concern and)Question :**
My concern is it OK or preventable to pass the UnitOfWork instance as a parameter to strategies and Commit the changes in the root method?
How can I avoid passing the UnitOfWork instance as a parameter to strategies but still make them work as a part of unit of work?

(I don't like the fact that someone can call .Commit inside strategy implementations by mistake -which I do not want)

```
public void DoTheJob(CustomerRequest req)
{

 var materialsPikcerStrategyFactory = new PickerStrategyFactory();
 var productionStrategyFactory = new ProductionStrategyFactory();

 var materialsPickerStrategy = materialsPikcerStrategyFactory.GetStrategy(req); 
 var productionStrategy = productionStrategyFactory.GetStrategy(req);

 using (var uow = new UnitOfWorkFactory() )
 {
    var materials = materialsPickerStrategy.PickMaterials(req, uow);
    var products = productionStrategy.CreateProductsWith(materials, uow);
    uow.Commit();
 }

}


puplic abstract class MaterialsPickerStrategy 
{

 // Picks some material entities from Db and modifies some of its properties before usage
 public abstract ICollection<Material> PickMaterials(CustomerRequest req, IUnitOfWorkFactory uow);

}

public abstract class ProductionStrategy
{
 // Gets the materials and creates some new instances by ADD'ing them to the repository
 public abstract void CreateProductsWith (ICollection<Material> materials, IUnitOfWorkFactory uow);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your code is using only unit of work but not repositories. They are usually use together to solve your problem. Repository is responsible for fetching data from database or registering changes in current unit of work and unit of work is responsible for committing registered changes. That would allow you passing repositories to your strategies and strategy will not have access to unit of work.

In terms of EF `ObjectContext` / `DbContext` can be considered as unit of work and `ObjectSet` / `DbSet` can be considered as repository. If you have custom unit of work and custom repositories they must all share single EF context instance.

Comment: So instead of paassing UnitOfWork, I can pass repositories which are properties of the UnitOfWork I use. Like uow.MaterialsRepository

Answer (score 1):

I would have a UnitOfWork that I passed as a dependency to whatever class needed to do the commit, which in your case if, I understand, you don't want to be your strategies.

The UnitOfWork should know about how to commit your updates because it would have a reference to some kind of data context.  Maybe and entity framework model, DBContext, etc.

Your strategies shouldn't know about the UnitOfWork if they are not supposed to commit.  I'm guessing maybe your using the UnitOfWork to expose your data context to your strategies.

Your strategies and your UnitOfWork should both have references to the same data context.   Then your strategies work with the context and some other routine, it may have used many strategies, would have a reference to the UnitOfWork to commit it at the end.

This is all quite straight forward if you are using an IOC framework because you would specify the lifetime scope of the data context as PerRequest and you would pass it as a dependency to both of your classes.  When the framework injected that dependency into your class it would use the same instance so your strategies would be writing to the same instance held by the unit of work.  In this way the changes you make to the data through your strategies are the same changes the unit of work is going to commit.  If you are really slick with the IOC you can actually inject the individual parts of the context needed by a given class further isolating the dependency.